# Php: repeating the navigation 2 times

Tags: php, class

I am quite new in php! 
I want to create a class for the navigation of my little cms.
It works properly except for one thing: all the page and subpages are displayed not one time as it should be but two times..
Can you help me please!

This is how i call the class:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="navigation">

     <?php

      $navigation_object = new Navigation();
      $navigation_object->navigation();
     ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the class:

```
class Navigation {

  var $nav_set;
  var $nav;
  var $selected_nav;
  var $page_set;
  var $page;
  var $selected_page;
  public $output = NULL;




 public function navigation() {

    //_____________________________ NAV _____________________________

     // 3. Performing database query for table NAV


    $get_all_nav_object2 = new Get_all_nav();
    $this->nav_set = $get_all_nav_object2->get_all_nav_function(); 


     // 4. Using returned data for table NAV (in variable $nav_set)

     while ($this->nav = mysql_fetch_array($this->nav_set)) {

              $output = "<li"; 
              if ($this->nav["id"] == $this->selected_nav['id']) {
              $output .= " class=\"selected\"";
              }
              $output .=  "><a href=\"content.php?nav_id=" . urlencode($this->nav["id"]) . 
              "\">{$this->nav["nav_name"]}</a></li>";





     // _____________________________ PAGES _______________________________________

       // 3b. Performing database query for table PAGES (sub-navigation)

       $get_pages_object1 = new Get_pages_for_nav();
       $this->page_set = $get_pages_object1->get_pages_for_nav_function($this->nav["id"]);

        $output .=  "<ul class=\"sub_navigation\">";



             // 4b. Using returned data for table PAGES (in variable $page_set)

             while ($this->page = mysql_fetch_array($this->page_set)) {

              $output .=  "<li";
              if ($this->page["id"] == $this->selected_page['id']) {
                $output .=  " class=\"selected\"";
              }
              $output .=  "><a href=\"content.php?page_id=" . urlencode($this->page["id"]) .
               "\">{$this->page["page_name"]}</a></li>";

                }  

             $output .=  "</ul>"; //closing ul for sub_navigation
             echo $output;

     }   // END of the previous while:  while ($nav = mysql_fetch_array($nav_set))
  } // end function
} // end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fell into some strange legacy behaviour of php. Prior to PHP 5, **class methods with the exact same name than the class** were considered beeing a constructor. That´s kept due to backwards compatibility.

**The result is that navigation() is executed twice: once on creation, once again on distinct call. Rename either the class or the method to solve it.**

More about constructors and destructors can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 1):

Because the first method in your class has the same name as the class, it is automatically run when the class is instantiated. This is called a [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), and means you don't need to call `$navigation_object->navigation();`

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct()
>   function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a
>   parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function,
>   by the name of the class.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
Not only i resolve the problem, but i also understand at last how it works the method __construct!!
Thank you Adam!

Answer (score 1):

Its because your `navigation()` function is named the same as your class (`navigation`).

In old PHP, this means that the `navigation()` function acts as the constructor, which is called automatically whenever you create a new instance of the object.

Remove the following line:

```
$navigation_object->navigation();
```

Or change the name of your `navigation()` method and call that instead